# Yii: div htmlOptions drops after ajaxLink was triggered

Tags: php, html, yii

So I have an empty div, kinda shell, with style attribute:

```
<div id="res" style="z-index: 99"></div>
```

Div's content is loading by ajaxLink:

```
CHtml::ajaxLink('toggle','my/action',array(
    'success'=>'function(html){ $("res").html(html); }'
));
```

But after the content was loaded, style attribute is replaced.

Thq question is: May ajaxLink keep current setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got a lot of mistakes in your code and software pattern. So ... lets give this a try:

**1)** Your jQuery selector is wrong. You tried to select "res" Tags. Take a look at this correct selector. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
CHtml::ajaxLink('toggle','my/action',array(
    'success'=>'function(html){ $("#res").html(html); }'
));
```

**2)** http://api.jquery.com/html/ will not replace your div, it will append your HTML as childs nodes. Thats why, your div will never be changed. Means, the problem is not about your missing "style" attribute.

**3)** Tip: Dont use inline CSS style. Go on with css-classes like

```
   #res { z-index:99 }
```

**4)** Try this to debug it in frontend/console:

```
CHtml::ajaxLink('toggle','my/action',array(
    'success'=>'function(html){ console.log(html); $("#res").html(html); }'
));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Code that I submited is just an expample, explaining what my code should do.
Yeah, i misspelled `#` before `res` :)
I'm assumed of how `html` method works, and I use styling class' at most, but in this case i have to style divs depending on external settings.
As a temporary workaround i've added some styles I need to the script query: `'success'=>'function(html){ console.log(html); $("#res").html(html)**.css({...})**; }'`

Comment: yea, sorry. I can't really remember how this has ended, but your response is still trully usefull